Send email from google spreadsheet is not working
I am not able to sent email
I need a JS script which will go through sheet which has the next columns (First Name, Last Name, Date of birth, Email, Date of examination, Future date of examination) and based on the date which is one month before today will send automatically reminder email
Here is the code
When I run at the end, everything looks good but I do not recieve
function sendExamReminders() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  const data = dataRange.getValues();

  const today = new Date();
  const oneMonthFromToday = new Date(today);
  oneMonthFromToday.setMonth(today.getMonth() + 1);
  oneMonthFromToday.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);  // Reset time to midnight for comparison

  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {  // Start at 1 to skip header row
    const row = data[i];
    const firstName = row[0];
    const lastName = row[1];
    const email = row[3];
    const futureDateOfExam = new Date(row[5]);

    if (isSameDate(futureDateOfExam, oneMonthFromToday)) {
      const subject = 'Examination Reminder';
      const message = `Dear ${firstName} ${lastName},

This is a reminder that your next examination is scheduled for ${futureDateOfExam.toDateString()}.

Best regards,
Your Examination Team`;

      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
    }
  }
}

function isSameDate(date1, date2) {
  return date1.getDate() === date2.getDate() &&
         date1.getMonth() === date2.getMonth() &&
         date1.getFullYear() === date2.getFullYear();
}

function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendExamReminders')
           .timeBased()
           .everyDays(1)
           .atHour(9)
           .create();
}

email.
